# Angular material sidenav inside tab's body

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Is it valid to load sidenav inside mat-tab like below?

```
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="test">
    <mat-sidenav-container>
      <mat-sidenav>
        <h1>Sidenav</h1>
      </mat-sidenav>
      <h1>Main Content</h1>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Comment: Did it work for you?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem, within the mattab (angular/material v5.x), the appropriate styles were not applied to show sidenav.
I could fix it by adding the following style to mat-sidenav:

```
.sidenav-fix {
   transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
   visibility: visible;
}

<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="test">
    <mat-sidenav-container>
      <mat-sidenav class="sidenav-fix" opened="true">
        <h1>Sidenav</h1>
      </mat-sidenav>
      <h1>Main Content</h1>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

As I see, with material 6, it is working without adding this class.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but probably it does not show because the mat-tab-group and side nav depend on a height of the container, in that case, use a height style in both components to show in the page.

Answer (score 0):

I have got a similar problem using the OP's approach. my sidenav is not displaying it does if I resize it, but switching tabs does not

Comment: What is the content you are trying to load inside the tab?

Comment: I'm trying to load mat side-nav in tabs